# will database.savepoint work for delete operation

Tags: apex, savepoint

i have scenario like in a single transaction i am doing 2 DML operation.
First one is delete,second one is update.
If i get any issue while update the record , the deleted record should be reverted back (should be undeleted)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will work for the delete DML operation. From the documentation [**Transaction Control**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_transaction_control.htm):

> Only when all the Apex code has finished running and the Visualforce
>   page has finished running, are the changes committed to the database.
>   If the request does not complete successfully, **all database changes
>   are rolled back**.

With regards to the Savepoint statement:

> **Any DML statement** that occurs after the savepoint can be discarded,
>   and the database can be restored to the same condition it was in at
>   the time you generated the savepoint.

It means that delete operation will be rolled back. In your code you have to make sure you use `Database.rollback(sp);` statement to rollback to the previous state.